# cannot convert 'double(_cdecl*)()' to 'double'

Tags: c++

As an assignment I have to write a code that takes user inputs, performs an operation with them, then prints them to the screen. However, I keep getting an error on line 18 where I call FunctionMultiply saying that the function cannot convert 'double(_cdecl*)()' to 'double'. I searched for this type of problem but it seems like all of them have to do with arrays which aren't in my code. How can I fix this?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int GetInt(void);
double GetDouble();
char GetLetter(void);
double FunctionMultiply(int, double);
int FunctionCharacter(char);

int main()
{
    GetInt();
    GetDouble();
    GetLetter();
    FunctionMultiply(GetInt, GetDouble);
    FunctionCharacter(GetLetter);
    printf("%f", FunctionMultiply);
    printf("%c", FunctionCharacter);
    return 0;
}

int GetInt(void)
{
    int integer;
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%i", &integer);
    return integer;
}

double GetDouble()
{
    double dub;
    printf("Enter a floating point number\n");
    scanf(" %lf", &dub);
    return dub;
}

char GetLetter(void)
{
    char letter;
    printf("Enter a letter\n");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
    return letter;
}


double FunctionMultiply(int arg1, double arg2)
{
    double product = arg1 * arg2;
    return product;
}

int FunctionCharacter(char letter)
{
    if (toupper(letter) <= 'M')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: FunctionCharacter(GetLetter());

Comment: Would be easier with [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing function identifiers with storage.  You have just called a bunch of functions at the beginning and not stored their results in anything.

It appears that you expect using the function identifier on its own will give you the result of the last call to that function.  But it does not.

Here is how you would store the return values and use them later:

```
int my_int = GetInt();
double my_double = GetDouble();
char my_char = GetLetter();

double multiply_result = FunctionMultiply( my_int, my_double );
char char_result = FunctionCharacter( my_char );

printf( "%f", multiply_result );
printf( "%c", char_result );
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `main()` like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = GetInt();
    double d = GetDouble();
    char c = GetLetter();
    double a = FunctionMultiply(i, d);
    char c = FunctionCharacter(c);
    printf("%f", a);
    printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is that you are passing function names rather than calling them.  i.e. `GetInt` instead of `GetInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you weren't paying attention to the lessons or examples showing how to use functions.

```
GetInt();
```

This calls the `GetInt` function, and ignores its return value.

```
GetDouble();
```

This calls the `GetDouble` function, and ignores its return value.

```
GetLetter();
```

This calls the `GetLetter` function, and ... you know the score by now.

```
FunctionMultiply(GetInt, GetDouble);
```

This is just nonsense. You're trying to call the `FunctionMultiply` function, passing the functions `GetInt` and `GetDouble` as arguments. You need to pass it an `int` and `double`, but you don't have an `int` and a `double` because you didn't store the results of `GetInt` and `GetDouble` anywhere.

You should have done this:

```
int i = GetInt();
double d = GetDouble();
char l = GetLetter();
```

Now you have variables `i`, `d` and `l` that hold the results of those function calls, so you can pass them in to other functions:

```
FunctionCharacter(i, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that the name of a function magically changes to the result of the call, after you've called the function once.

It doesn't.  The function call expression itself is the result of the call.

Instead of

```
ReturnADouble();
//  call ^  and  value v somehow separated?  Why did you ever think that?
double result = ReturnADouble;
```

But according to the language rules, `ReturnADouble` is still the name of a function, and the compiler righteously complains when you give the name of a function when you should be giving a numeric value.

Your code should read more like

```
double result = ReturnADouble();
             // ^ this call results in a value
```